# Editing XML node attributes in R

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML file that I need to edit with R. For specific nodes I need to change one attribute depending on the value of a different attribute. Let me try to clarify, here is some code and the resulting object:

```
>xmlfile = xmlParse("example.txt")
>print(xmlfile)

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GColumn Name="Gross">
  <dataHead>
    <data year="2015" value="0"/>
    <data year="2016" value="0"/>
  </dataHead>
</GColumn>

>gCol=getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//GColumn[@Name='Gross']")
>gItem = gCol[[1]][[1]]
>print(class(gemItem))
[1] "XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode"       
[3] "XMLAbstractNode"
>print(gItem)

<dataHead>
  <data year="2015" value="0"/>
  <data year="2016" value="0"/>
</dataHead>

# the mapping of years to values
>map = matrix(data=c(2015,1,2016,2),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
>print(map)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2015    1
[2,] 2016    2
```

How do I edit the value attribute? Furthermore, I have a matrix matching a certain value to each year (e.g., 2015 corresponds to 1, 2016 corresponds to 2). How could I edit each value according to this mapping?

EDIT:

I think I found a solution, thanks to the suggestion to visit the xmlAttrs() function.

```
setYears = 2000:2100
setValues = 1:length(setYears) # dummy values
setMap = data.frame(setYears,setValues)

# create function to change the "value" attribute depending upon the "year", drawing upon the mapping in the setMap dataframe

changeXML <- function(obj){
    xmlAttrs(obj)=c(value=match( as.numeric(xmlGetAttr(obj,"year")),setMap$setYears))
}

xmlSApply(dataHead,changeXML)
```

Comment: look at the help for `xmlAttrs`. Without the actual data it's going to be difficult to show you a complete example.

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr. I've added actual data to the post and am looking into the xmlAttrs function again.

Comment: I found a solution using xmlAttrs, match and xmlSApply. Thanks!